# The 'MapPath' method cease to work as soon as it's procedure is moved to a C# class file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using C# ASP.NET VS2010.

I have a procedure on an .aspx.cs that reads a XML file and works just fine.

It goes like this:

```
string fileName = "~/App_Data/" + filename + ".xml";
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXml(MapPath(fileName));
```

I use this procedure alot to read various files with minimal changes (the file name), therefore, I tried to put the procedure in a Class1.cs file (in the App_Code folder), but I get this error message:

```
The type or namespace name 'MapPath' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Server' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

I use this MapPath to read an XML file into a dataset this way:

```
ds.ReadXml(Server.MapPath(fileName));
```

The filename is a string variable declared a few lines earlier:

```
string fileName = "~/App_Data/" + inputString + ".xml";
```

After putting this line in the class.cs file, the VS2010 asked to resolve the missing `Server` by replacing it into `Microsoft.SqlServer.Server` locally (at the same line and not by adding a namespace) , so the line in it's new form looks like this:

```
ds.ReadXml(Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.MapPath(fileName));
```

For the record, I made sure that all namespaces on the source .aspx.cs file are at the class file.

Why the difference between the Class1.cs and the .aspx.cs?

How do I workaround this?

What should I change in order to read the XML file from this new class file?

Is there a replacement for my line to read the XML file into the dataset?

Comment: have you debugged and checked the Server.MapPath(filename) by selecting the line and (control D,Q) from your keyboard, check if the file exist in the path

Comment: skhurams- The file exists. The procedure works in code behind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MapPath` is method of the `System.Web.HttpServerUtility` class, you need an instance of this class to call the method. In ASP pages, an instance is available in the Server member of the Page; elsewhere, you'll have to supply it. Either as

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(fileName);
```

which uses the `Server` variable for the current `HttpContext` if you're inside one. `HttpContext` class contains many HTTP-related objects that you're used to access through `Page` members - like Request, Response, Server. The `Current` static property gives the context for the request you're currently handling. Inside classes in App_Code folder of your ASP web project, you're safe to assume that there's an active context.

If you wanted to move your class to a separate assembly, it would be better to make the Server (or Context) a parameter of your method and make it the responsibility of the caller to supply one:

```
public class Class1
{
    public void MyMethod(HttpServerUtility server)
    {
        //...
        server.MapPath(fileName);
        //...
    }
}
```

From the ASP page it would then be called like `class1instance.MyMethod(this.Server);`

`Microsoft.SqlServer.Server` has nothing to do with it, only the class/member names are the same and Visual Studio got it wrong.

Comment: Tieson T. - using System.Web; is not enough - it doesn't work.

Comment: pjotr - I tried several things, but nothing works. If you may, please put some example code. Thanks.

Comment: @Different111222 - added more detail, hth

Comment: pjotr- Thanks, but what are the changes I must make in the line `ds.ReadXml(MapPath(fileName));` in order for it to work?

Comment: @Different111222 - as I wrote - the simplest way is to change it to `ds.ReadXml(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(fileName));`

Comment: pjotr- Many thanks - that works!
I've just added your last markup to the bottom of your answer.